# Search in SIM contacts doesn't work

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to implement searching onto phone and SIM contacts. Using `lookup Uri` I can search phone contacts. But I am unable to find any similar `lookup Uri` for searching into SIM directory.

I even tried including `selection` and `selection arguments` in my query to fetch only relevant contacts but still no success. It seems like the `selection` and `selection arguments` are simply ignored while executing query because I'm getting all the available SIM contacts.

My implementation to fetch particular contacts:

```
public Cursor getCursorForSIMContactsLike(Activity context,String constraint) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "name", "number" };
        String selection = "name LIKE ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { constraint +"%" };
        String sortOrder = "name" + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in this query? Or if anyone has any other techniques to perform searching over SIM contacts - please suggest.

Comment: Why are you using "content://icc/adn"?  Shouldn't it just be "content://"  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html#CONTENT_URI) Unless you are looking explicitly for SIM contacts, then they are treated the same as normal contacts.